# OpenLayers: zDirection in raster tiles vs. vector tiles

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector-tiles

I've got a map that changes its tile source on non-integer zoom levels using the approach [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344604/openlayers-smoothly-change-tile-source-on-zoom).  The zoom level is used with a virtual tile grid to call the `loadTiles` function. The actual z coordinate and the directory that should be used to load tiles from is then calculated from the current `zoom`.

```js
function loadTiles(tileCoordinate) {
    const zoom = tileCoordinate[0];
    const x = tileCoordinate[1];
    const y = tileCoordinate[2];
    const z = tileloader.tileserverZs[zoom];
    const path = ... // different paths depending on currZoom 

    return path;
}
```

Suppose I have two versions of the function, differing only in the directories they're using.

This works nicely for raster tiles. Now I'm trying to mirror this behaviour with vector tiles, which have the same 256x256 size and file structure as the raster tiles.

```js
var raster = new TileLayer({
        source: new XYZ({
          tileGrid: virtualTileGrid,
          tileUrlFunction: loadTiles_raster,
          zDirection: 0,
        }),
        preload: 0,                         
        useInterimTilesOnError: false,      
});

var vector = new VectorTileLayer({
        source: new VectorTileSource({
            format: new MVT(),
            tileGrid: virtualTileGrid,
            tileUrlFunction: loadTiles_vector,
            zDirection: 0,
          }),
          preload: 0,
          useInterimTilesOnError: false,
          style: // ...
});
```

In both cases, `zDirection` is set to 0 (whereas the default for vector tiles would be `1`). However, using this setup, both layers do not behave in the same way.

*This is the behaviour I get:*

```js
start
mode: raster    zoom:  0    
mode: vector    zoom:  1    
zoom 
mode: raster    zoom:  1    
zoom 
mode: raster    zoom:  2    
mode: vector    zoom:  1    
zoom 
mode: raster    zoom:  3    
mode: vector    zoom:  2
```

*Notice several things here:*

1. Raster tiles and vector tiles already start at different zoom levels. As I'm calculating another z value and the directory of the used tiles from this, in my use case this is noticeable immediately as the vector layers uses wrong tiles.
2. The first zoom operation does not lead the vector layer to reload.
3. Both layers stay asynchronous after zooming in deeper.

I've tried using zDirection=1 for the vector layer but then it's wrong in a different way. Actually, I'd expect to see an identical behaviour of both layers as they're having the same attribute for zDirection.

*This would be the expected behaviour:*

```js
start
mode: raster    zoom:  0    
mode: vector    zoom:  0    
zoom 
mode: raster    zoom:  1
mode: vector    zoom:  1        
zoom 
mode: raster    zoom:  2    
mode: vector    zoom:  2    
zoom 
mode: raster    zoom:  3    
mode: vector    zoom:  3
```

In other words, both layers should be synchronized.

Comment: It works as expected for me, with the same tilegrid and zDirection both raster and vector tiles are called with the same tileCoord[0] and the changeover starts at the same view zoom value (although by the time the final tiles are called the view zoom may have changed) https://codesandbox.io/s/osm-vector-tiles-forked-wocpc

Comment: @Mike I think it might be restricted to my specific use case for which I have used a solution you kindly had provided earlier. I have now mixed the two sandboxes you gave in your examples and I think I can reproduce the error in the sandbox (the mismatch between vector and raster tiles is visible in the console), see https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-qy5gg?file=/index.js

Comment: The tileUrlFunction is not being called as frequently as expected with that grid with a vector tile source.  Maybe vector tiles presume a fixed tile size?

Comment: Similar to reprojection for raster tiles the vector tile source creates an internal grid for rendering, which assumes a fixed tile size https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/VectorTile.js#L433

Comment: Just for clarification: So what I want to achieve is not possible using this method?

Comment: For vector tiles I think it is not possible by that method, but you could have multiple vector tile layers and/or use resolution based styling

Comment: @Mike Thank you very much, this might have saved me from spending more time with what couldn't be solved in the way I intended. Thanks also for pointing out the alternative way. Still, I have opened a feature request as this behaviour seems rather unexpected to me. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12590